# In Visual Studio for MacOS, how do I get the iOS simulators to show in dropdown list?

Tags: ios, macos, visual-studio, build, maui

I'm running Xcode 14.0 and Visual Studio for Mac, 17.3.5. The simulators don't show up in the dropdown menu where you can select the device you're using to run the app. I've verified that the Preferences | Apple SDK is pointed at Xcode.app, and that Xcode is located in the Applications folder. Why are the simulators not showing, and how can I fix it. Also: when I plug in a phone via USB, VS *does* successfully see the phone.

Comment: Xcode 14 support has not been released yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason suggested, `XCode 14` is not yet supported in `Xamarin.iOS` or `.NET MAUI`, you need downgrade your Xcode version to 13.4.1 and could download it from the [downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/) page in the Apple Developer Portal. For more information, you can refer to https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15954

**Update:**

`Xcode 14` is currently supported, you need to upgrade your VS to **17.3.6** and if there are any other issues, please continue to post back to the GitHub.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 17.3.6 was released yesterday which includes support for Xcode 14.0 on .NET 6